# how to target ul with css in @mui/material/Menu

Tags: css, material-ui

I am trying to apply the following styles to the `ul` that appears once the button is clicked:

```
 &.MuiList-root {
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
  }
```

Here is a live sandbox where problem is illustrated:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-tyd8n8?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the posted sandbox, the styles are attached to `CustomMenuItem` which is the list items. To target the list and remove the padding, consider to style the `Menu` instead, with the `sx` prop (or create a custom component with `styled`):

Forked live with modification: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-vmb6tm?file=/src/App.tsx:974-1313)

```
<Menu
  {...bindMenu(popupState)}
  sx={{
    "& .MuiList-root": {
      py: "0px",
    },
  }}
>
  <CustomMenuItem
    onClick={() => {
      console.log("hello");
      popupState.close();
    }}
  >
    label
  </CustomMenuItem>
</Menu>
```